# How to make a numeric textField in Drupal WebForm?

Tags: 7, webforms

Can anyone suggest how to make a *numeric only* textfield in WebForm for a mobile number field?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Webform validation](http://drupal.org/project/webform_validation) module to create such validation.

Answer (score 0):

The following features of the [Webform Validation](http://drupal.org/project/webform_validation) module will help you

The following validation rules are currently included:

Numeric values (optionally specify min and / or max value)
Minimum length
Maximum length
Minimum number of words
Maximum number of words